# What is a standard Akka.Net Message Command Validation Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, generics, akka.net

Many of our messages need validation before they can be safely handled. Input being checked and sometimes complex business rules being applied.

In a pre Akka design I would have had an `ICommandValidator<T>` with a single method `IsValid` and a property of errors. So a concrete validatior would tell you if a message was valid and if not you can read the errors.

In Akka.Net I started writing concrete Validator actors for each message (apparently creating more actors is good) - for example CreateTenantCommand is sent by TenantCreatorActor (inheriting from ReceiveActor) to the CreateTenantCommandValidatorActor for validation. If it is valid a CreateTenantCommandValidated message (basically the original message wrapped up) is sent to the TenantCreateActor and it unwraps the message and it then processes the message.

I wondered if I should be storing a list of unvalidated messages with the actor that needs them validated and then correlating these to validation response or should I send the whole message to be validated back and forth? The validator needs the whole message to validate however I wasn't sure of the benefits of keeping the message intact on the requesting actor and only confirming its validity?

Is it common to use generics in Akka.Net messages and Actors? It just seems like an area that contains a lot of boilerplate but I've never really seen much generics in any examples so that got me worried. I had a design that looks like:

```
public class IsValidCommand<TCommamd>{

    public TCommamd Command { get; private set; }
    Ctor....
}
public class ValidCommand<TCommamd>
{
    public TCommamd Command { get; private set; }
    Ctor....
}
public class InvalidCommand<TCommamd>
{
    public TCommamd Command { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; private set; }
    Ctor....
}
```

Other approach is to create a combined `ValidatedCommand<T>`

```
public class ValidatedCommand<T>
{
    public T Command { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; }
    public bool IsValid => !Errors.Any();

    Ctor...
}
```

I can then create a generic ValidatorActor and inject a validator class into it. E.g.

```
var createValidatorProps = Props.Create(() => new ValidatorActor<CreateInstanceCommand>(Self, new CreateInstanceCommandValidator()));
CreateInstanceCommandValidatorActor = Context.ActorOf(createValidatorProps, "CreateInstanceCommandValidatorActor");
```

With the generic validator actor like:

```
public class ValidatorActor<T> : ReceiveActor{
    public IActorRef Requestor { get; }
    public ValidatorActor(IActorRef requestor, ICommandValidator<T> validator)
    {
        Requestor = requestor;
        Receive<IsValidCommand<T>>(
            commandWrapper =>
                {
                    var command = commandWrapper.Command;
                    if (validator.Validate(command))
                    {
                        requestor.Tell(new ValidCommand<T>(command));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        requestor.Tell(new InvalidCommand<T>(command));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Possibly should note I realise it should probably be `ValidateAsync` and then `PipeTo` so the actor doesn't block. So that probably requires the `ValidatedCommand<T>` approach to be returned from the ValidateAsync method

This means that these messages can be standardized. Is this an appropriate way to deal with message validation in Akka.Net or am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: How did this work out for you? I'm planning an app with Akka and was wondering the same things that you've brought up. It's too bad no one has replied yet :(

Answer (score 1):

My word is not gospel, i'm just another hacker hacking away giving my hack opinons for the pundits to shoot at.

re passing messages about. Ideally you want to keep everything small. But also things arn't getting serialised on a local system you don't need to worry (I am 99.9% sure about this). Over a remoting boundary then i think you have a valid concern.

However is this a premature optimisation question? do it one way, if its a problem then profile it and decide then.

re generics, yes I have found some really nice uses. Common, not really. But when it works and is the right place it is elegant imo. I was genuinely excited when i discovered it worked.

But that is probably not sufficient answer.

Have used similar patterns for observation into a callback but also for validation and when i want to write really geric proxy like actors (eg guranteed message delivery)

Comment: what? a developer's word not gospel ?  "P

Comment: Glad what I am implementing doesn't seem to crazed then :). Guess there isn't a lot of blogs/artiicles on Akka.Net yet so hopefully I will get a better understanding of real world usage in a few months